# Randint number into a Dict

Tags: python, random

Is it possible to add a random number create with random.randint to a Dict ? Or is it better to add it to a List. I ask because I wan to get random.randit(0,100) and check it the List or Dict have already the number that is now generated and print out the possition on which the second same number is

So I already tried it with append to a dict but that doesn' work!

**EDIT**

```
import random
randomdict = {}
numbposition = {}
def randomnumber(numb):

    for i in random.randint(0,numb+1):
        randomdict.append(i)
        if i in randomdict:
            numbposition.index(i)
            print (numbposition)
            print (randomdict)
while True:
    numb = int(input('Give me number: '))
    print(randomnumber(numb))
    break
```

Comment: Yes, of course it is - what have you tried, and what precisely do you mean it doesn't work? You `append` to a `list`, not to a `dict`.

Comment: Please show what you did try that didn't work.  Your description of what you want is not very clear, and maybe the code might be more illuminating.

Comment: just a moment I will add it

Comment: FWIW, dictionaries are unordered, so it doesn't make sense to say what position a key has in it.

Comment: In your code, you check `if i in randomdict` *after* you try to add it - of course it's there, why bother to check? What is the bigger picture here; what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible to add the value returned by `random.randint` to a dictionary or list; it's just an integer, and can be treated like any other. However, you cannot `append` to a dictionary; that syntax is for adding to the end of a list, to add a new object to a dictionary use `d[key] = value`. Also, dictionaries don't have an index in the same way that e.g. lists and tuples do; just a key, and no guaranteed order.

Here is an example that is close to what you're describing:

```
import random

l = []
for _ in range(10):
    n = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(n)
    if n not in l:
        print("New item.")
        l.append(n)
    else:
        print("Item found at index {0}.".format(l.index(n)))
print(l)
```

The output from this is:

```
2
New item.
2
Item found at index 0.
2
Item found at index 0.
1
New item.
3
New item.
10
New item.
6
New item.
4
New item.
4
Item found at index 5.
10
Item found at index 3.
[2, 1, 3, 10, 6, 4]
```

---

**Edit**

To add all numbers and get the largest preexisting index, you need a slight tweak:

```
if n not in l:
    print("New item.")
else:
    index = max(i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v == n)
    print("Item found at index {0}.".format(index))
l.append(n)
```

Note that `append` is moved to the end (so the new `n` isn't in the list when we look for the largest prior index) and we can no longer use `list.index` (which finds the *first* index) - a more complex calculation is required.

This gives:

```
0
New item.
4
New item.
10
New item.
10
Item found at index 2.
3
New item.
4
Item found at index 1.
1
New item.
8
New item.
8
Item found at index 7.
1
Item found at index 6.
[0, 4, 10, 10, 3, 4, 1, 8, 8, 1]
```

Comment: But you can ask if the number is in a dict, so if I want to add it into a dict I have to give every number a key or ?

Comment: You could use a `set`, which is effectively a dictionary with only keys, but they don't have a guaranteed order or index either. You could put the random numbers into the dictionary as values with their indices as keys, but then you might as well use a list.

Comment: your code don't give the postion of the second same number maybe if the 1 is on position 5 and the second on 12 it should give out the 12

Comment: and in works only with a few number if the range is >20  it tells your  not the corret position

Comment: So you want the numbers to be added to the list even if they're already there? And the *largest* index to be printed out?

Comment: I  already tried it out with adding append but now it don't print out  that the number (the second same number) is even printed out and also don#t give out the postion of the 'second same ' number

Comment: `index` returns the *first* index; for the last, you need something like: `max(i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v == n)`

Comment: so it says that all numbers a new even if the number already is shown

Comment: @Kate I have added an edit to my question which should address this

Comment: enumerate also give you the first index... please look at your edit result your see that the first 10 is on position 2 and the second on 3, but the text result is Item found at index 2 but the second 10 is on the 3 so it should print out "Number is even in the list the second one have the position 3"

Comment: so after how many random numbers, the first
Repetition appear  and his position 0,5,9,...9 and the position of the  second nine

Comment: So you want it to stop when it reaches a duplicate and give the index at which it has stopped? It would really help if you clearly explained precisely what you're trying to achieve, e.g. with example outputs.

Comment: no it should continue, but tells us after how many random numbers, the first Repetition appear and that for all number between the range

Comment: so if if the second 5  was generated after 10 random numbers and the 3  after 17 ...

Comment: So for each number that could possibly be in the list, you want all indices (if any) at which it appears in the list?

Comment: I mean  for all random numbers that are genereted in the range for ex. 10... it could look like... 1,5,7,9.10,5,6,8,9,10... now the first repetiton is 5 on postion 5 but that is 6 tries with random number until we get a repetiton, the second that comes twice is 9 and the second nine is on position 8 but there are nine tries

Comment: it simply should print out after how many random numbers the first repetition the second and..... appear